# MessageBox - HWND parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, messagebox

I am working on an MFC application and I am adding some error checking with the use of `MessageBox` which has documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox).

```
int MessageBox(
  [in, optional] HWND    hWnd,
  [in, optional] LPCTSTR lpText,
  [in, optional] LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  [in]           UINT    uType
);
```

`Note: The utype parameter is a list of styles separated with |`

Above is `MessageBox`'s implementation. My question is about the HWND parameter. When writing my call to `MessageBox`, Visual Studio 2017 Professional did not ask for the HWND parameter. At first, I thought it was because it is optional, but the other two optional `LPCTSTR` parameters were not as optional as they seemed, and required me to put at least `""` to satisfy them.

Currently, my call to `MessageBox` only uses the last three parameters. My call is:

`int BoxReturnVal = MessageBox("foo1", "foo2", MB_OK | MB_ICON);`.

My question is why is the `HWND` parameter not asked for while writing the call to the function and do I need to worry about it all?

Thank you in advance ! :D

Comment: Note the difference between a free `::MessageBox()` function and a [member `CWnd::MessageBox()` one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#messagebox).

Comment: Change the scope of the call to global `::MessageBox` and you will see an error regarding the `HWND` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the `MessageBox()` function that you think you are.

You are looking at the [`MessageBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) function in the Win32 API, but MFC has its own [`MessageBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#messagebox) method in the [`CWnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170) class. The latter one, which does not have an `HWND` parameter, is the one you are actually calling.

Comment: Ah I see, one follow-up question, looking at the Cwnd class' messagebox function, it links to these [MFC styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/styles-used-by-mfc?view=msvc-170#message-box-styles), until reading your answer, I was using the Win32 API's message box style (MB_ICONERROR) which gives the red X which is the same as the MFC's style (MB_ICONSTOP) [win32's api also has MB_ICONSTOP which is an alias for MB_ICONERROR] . would there be any consequences to using win32 api's style if it working ? do you recommend simply using MB_ICONSTOP

Comment: `CWnd::MessageBox()` is just a wrapper for the Win32 `MessageBox()`, the parameters are passed as-is.  So the MFC version is just using the Win32 styles, there are no MFC styles defined for the `CWnd` method.

Comment: Interesting, so the styles on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/styles-used-by-mfc?view=msvc-170) page are the same styles as non-MFC programs ?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  MFC is a C++ class wrapper for Win32 APIs. That page you mention is even referring you to the relevant Win32 docs to learn more about each style.